# c# - How to read an int variable if it's an string

Tags: c#

I just encounter this in a test that said end the loop if the input is invalid then end the program. My code is like this

```
    int x=0;
    while(x!=(string)) // this is what I want to know what should i do here
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Input an integer: ");
    x = Int.Parse(Console.ReadLine);
  }
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
```

What is the proper way to do this?

P.S. 
 That time, I don't know `int.TryParse` yet. So I'm exactly looking for a way without using `int.TryParse`

Comment: C# is a strongly-typed language: a variable declared as an int can only ever be an int..

Comment: .. however if you enter something on the console that can't be parsed as an int, then the program **will** end. And not in a nice way.

Comment: Yeah I know that good sir, that's why I'm asking how the question in my test should be done properly. :)

Comment: What is considered invalid input? As currently written, your code won't even compile. If it *did* compile, it would throw an exception if the input was not a valid integer. That is, `Int.Parse()` would throw an exception if somebody entered "foobar". As it stands, your question is ambiguous enough that I don't know what your code is supposed to do, so I'm not going to try giving an answer.

Comment: Look at the MSDN docs on the `Parse()` and `TryParse()` methods of `Int32` - that should move you in the right direction.

Comment: @JimMischel The considered invalid is a string like `foobar` or `b`

Comment: I voted to re-open. This question is not a duplicate of "how to convert from string to int." That's *part* of the answer, but clearly not all of it. In particular, the answer to the supposed duplicate was `int.Parse`, which is totally inappropriate here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read a string, try to convert to an integer, and exit the program if it's not a valid integer, then you'd use [int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (int.TryParse(input, out x))
{
    // do something with x
}
else
{
    // input was invalid.
}
```

If you want to continue doing this in a loop until you got invalid input:

```
bool validInput = true;
while (validInput == true)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int x;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out x))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);  // output the integer
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input was not an integer");
        validInput = false;
    }
}
```

### Update

What, exactly, does your test consider "an integer?" Is it just a string that consists only of one or more digits in the set [0-9]? Or does it need to fit within the C# language's definition of `Int32`? If the former, then you can use a regular expression to determine if the string is just digits. Otherwise, `int.TryParse` or `int.Parse` wrapped in a `try ... catch` is the way you'll have to do it.

Comment: This is the correct answer sir. However, please try to look again in my edited question sir.

Comment: I tried this out and it worked. (The second statement). However, please look again in my edited question.

Comment: @Wowie: Well, you could replace `int.TryParse` with a `try / catch` block around `int.Parse`. Or around `Convert.ToInt32`. Either of those will work, although not so elegantly as `int.TryParse`.

Comment: Downvoter: If there's something in this answer that you take issue with, it's customary to leave a comment explaining your down vote.

Comment: @reds: No, it doesn't accept a Decimal number. The question specifically requested that it accept only integers.

Answer (score 2):

To me, this sounds like a job for a do-while loop with an int.tryparse.

A simple code example of this is as follows:

```
        string input = string.Empty;

        int x = 0;
        do
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (int.TryParse(input, out x));

        Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry");

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Do While works similar to a while loop, but it leaves the conditional to the end, which allows for a tryparse at the end.

Tryparse returns a boolean value of true when the value can be successfully parsed as an integer, otherwise, returning false and ending the loop.

Comment: This is a good answer. However, in practice, one will probably want to do something with good values.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
         Console.WriteLine("About to call Console.ReadLine in a loop.");
        Console.WriteLine("----");
        String s;

        do
        {

            s = Console.ReadLine();
            Regex regex = new Regex("[0-9]");
            Regex regex2 = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]");
            if (regex.IsMatch(s))
            {
                if (regex.IsMatch(s) && regex2.IsMatch(s))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered an combination of number and String = " + s.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    int cnt = s.Count(x => x == '.');
                    if (s.Count(x => x == '.') > 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input of number = " + s.ToString());
                    }
                    else if (s.Count(x => x == '.') == 1 && regex.IsMatch(s))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You entered a decimal number = " + s.ToString());
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        char[] str = "!@#$%^&*()',-./:;<=>?@_`{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©¬®¯°±²³´µ¶¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÈËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöL÷øùúûüýþÿ\"".ToArray();
                        int indexOf = s.IndexOfAny(str);

                        if (indexOf == -1)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("You entered a number = " + s.ToString());

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("You entered an combination of number and String = " + s.ToString());
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (s.Trim().Length < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter any value.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered a String = " + s.ToString());
                }

            }


        } while (s != null);
        Console.WriteLine("---");
```

Comment: Noice! But when I input values like this `w6`, `^6` it outputs an integer.

Comment: It will accept and return a correct value even you input a combination of any.

Comment: This does not work. In the first place, the value "123.456" is considered an integer. It does not allow for negative integers. Finally, you can eliminate most of your logic with a single statement: `bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(s, "^[0-9]+$");` If you're going to use regular expressions, at least use them effectively.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work 123.456 .. i tried it and consider as number.. thanks for your comment.. @Jim Mischel if you have an idea to improve the answer then go ahead edit mine. thanks

Comment: Updated the answer.. @Jim Mischel try to run it.

Comment: My point is that "123.456" is not an integer. It's a real number. And your code still would allow something like "12)34(", which clearly isn't generally recognized as any kind of number. An integer contains *only* the digits 0 through 9. Possibly a leading sign character (i.e. `-` or '+'). And, no, I don't need to edit your answer; I already supplied one. And, by the way, I think the regular expression `[a-zA-Z_@.-]*` will match every string. The `*` means "zero or more", and every string has zero or more of every character.

Comment: I think as tested this is the perfect one.

Comment: Your code *does not work*. There are over one million possible Unicode characters, every one of which can be entered by a user at the keyboard. In order for your technique to have any change of working, your string of disallowed characters would have to include all of those, except the digits 0-9. Even now, it misses a few, like the space and tab characters. I already gave you a way to improve your answer,: the regular expression `"^[0-9]+$"`, which matches a string that contains only the digits 0 through 9.

Comment: I knew it.. there's a lot of special characters.. but you can add anything if you wish.. how about yours?

Answer (score -2):

You define X as a int first and the X will always be int-type (),Unless you convert this int type,i think use try{...} catch{...} may be a good way to solve this:

```
string x;
int result;
while (true)
{
    x = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        result = int.Parse(x);
        Console.WriteLine("int input");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input ");
    }
}
```

or you can use regular expression like this:

```
var reg = new Regex("^-?\\d+$");
string result;
Match m;
for (;;)
{
    result = Console.ReadLine();
    m = reg.Match(result);
    if(m.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int input");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out `int.TryParse` instead of handling exceptions. Also, you have no way to break out of the loop. Finally, your output when an integer is correctly parsed is wrong.

Comment: thank ,in fact ,i know wrong with the word"Invalid",i thought it would be valid,i just know little about english